# Why duplicate query results, without "GROUP BY"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT C.ID_PASS, C.ID_MERCE, CTRL.ESITO, M.ID_CAT, M.QTA, M.DESCRIZ, 
   CTRL.ID_PUNTO, CTRL.ID_ADDETTO, C.DATE_OPEN, C.DATE_CLOSE, C.NOTE

FROM   CONTESTAZIONI C, CONTROLLI CTRL, FUNZIONARI F, ADDETTI A, MERCI M

WHERE  A.ID=CTRL.ID_ADDETTO
  AND    A.ID_FUNZ=501
  AND    M.ID=C.ID_MERCE
  AND    M.ID_PASS=C.ID_PASS
  AND    CTRL.ESITO > 1
GROUP  BY C.ID_PASS;
```

Why, if I don't add `GROUP BY C.ID_PASS`, do I get 20 rows (instead of 2).

Comment: You're joining 5 tables, but only have explicit relationships between two sets of them. (M<->C and A<->CTRL).

Answer (score 1):

You get a cross-product when doing joins with "," operator. You should include the IDs from all tables into your where clause!

Basically, you need to link all 5 tables together by ensuring equalities of their rows' IDs, because as noted in the comment, you have two groups of tables, but they are not linked and the resulting set thus has lots of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY is used to group rows together when using aggregate functions, such as SUM or COUNT.

If you had, for example, 4 records, with say 2 for each cust id, each with a value:-

```
CustId    Spend
1         10
1         20
2         30
2         40
```

If you wanted to know the total of each value for each customer you would use something like:-

```
SELECT CustId, SUM(Spend) FROM SomeTable GROUP BY CustId
```

This would give you

```
CustId    Sum(Spend)
1         30
2         70
```

Part of what it does is remove the duplicated rows and sum up all the values into one row.

It can be misused without an aggregate function to remove duplicates and this is what you have done. Hence 2 records instead of 20.

Note that if you have fields in the SELECT that are not in the GROUP BY variable, and which are not 100% dependent on the group by fields then the value of that field is indeterminate.

For example

```
CustId    Spend  ShopId
1         10     1
1         20     2
2         30     3
2         40     4
```

If you wanted to know the total of each value for each customer you would use something like:-

SELECT CustId, ShopId, SUM(Spend) FROM SomeTable GROUP BY CustId

This would give you

```
CustId    Sum(Spend)  ShopId
1         30          Could be 1 or could be 2
2         70          Could be 3 or could be 4
```

In your query this probably applies to the fields CTRL.ESITO, M.ID_CAT, M.QTA, M.DESCRIZ, 
   CTRL.ID_PUNTO, CTRL.ID_ADDETTO.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an implicit cross join on the tables. Try using different type of Join such as Inner, Right or Left.

example:

```
SELECT *
FROM CONTESTAZIONI c 
INNER JOIN CONTROLLI ctrl ON c.ID = ctrl.ContId
```

Answer (score 1):

One advantage of the modern (meaning post-1992) explicit JOIN notation is that you are less likely to forget joining conditions.  You have 5 tables; you need (at least) 4 join conditions.  Your SQL has only 2 join conditions (one of them a compound join).  You've not given us enough schema to be sure of coming up with the right columns for joining, but your query should probably be something like:

```
SELECT C.ID_PASS, C.ID_MERCE, CTRL.ESITO, M.ID_CAT, M.QTA, M.DESCRIZ, 
       L.ID_PUNTO, L.ID_ADDETTO, C.DATE_OPEN, C.DATE_CLOSE, C.NOTE
  FROM ADDETTI       A
  JOIN CONTROLLI     L ON A.ID = L.ID_Addetto
  JOIN CONTESTAZIONI C ON A.xxx1 = C.xxx2
  JOIN FUNZIONARI    F ON C.yyy1 = F.yyy2
  JOIN MERCI         M ON M.ID   = C.ID_Merce AND M.ID_Pass = C.ID_Pass
 WHERE A.ID_FUNZ=501
   AND L.ESITO > 1;
```

Note that you showed the join of A and L (renamed from CTRL), and M and C.  The joins of C to A and of F to C are semi-arbitrary guesses (and the column names `xxx1` etc are placeholders for your real column names); you will need to understand your schema and make the appropriate joins.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everbody. Now I understood: I have to join together all the tables that I put in select (of course only that are in relationship); without this join I get a cross product. I can do join either "JOIN...ON..." or "WHERE ...". I made join with WHERE. Now works ok:

```
SELECT C.ID_PASS, C.ID_PUNTO, C.ID_ADDETTO, C.TIME_START,
   C.TIME_END, C.ESITO, P.ID_NAZ, C.ID_MERCE, M.QTA, M.DESCRIZ, M.ID_CAT
FROM CONTROLLI C, PASSEGGERI P, MERCI M, FUNZIONARI F, CATEGORIE, ADDETTI, NAZIONI
WHERE 
    ADDETTI.ID=C.ID_ADDETTO
AND P.ID=M.ID_PASS 
AND P.ID_NAZ=NAZIONI.ID
AND M.ID_PASS=C.ID_PASS AND M.ID=C.ID_MERCE  -- composite PK (so another AND reuqired)
AND M.ID_CAT=CATEGORIE.ID
AND F.ID=ADDETTI.ID_FUNZ
AND ESITO > 1 
AND F.ID = 501
```